# Migrate Plone 3.0 to 4.1 issues

Tags: migration, plone

I am trying to migrate our plone site from windows server 2003 to run on a windows server 2008 box.  I installed Plone 4.1 on the 2008 server then copied the data.fs file from Plone 3.0.  I also found that I needed to copy the CMFPLONE extensions directory from 3.0 to the new version.  Once I did the the site came up but without any graphics.  When I tried to log in to see if I could correct the site style I received the following error:

We’re sorry, but there seems to be an error… 
Here is the full error message:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerPageTemplate, line 91, in __call__
  Module Products.CMFFormController.BaseControllerPageTemplate, line 28, in _call
  Module Products.CMFFormController.ControllerBase, line 231, in getNext
  Module Products.CMFFormController.Actions.TraverseTo, line 38, in __call__
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerPythonScript, line 105, in __call__
  Module Products.CMFFormController.Script, line 145, in __call__
  Module Products.CMFCore.FSPythonScript, line 130, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.PythonScripts.PythonScript, line 344, in _exec
  Module script, line 29, in logged_in <FSControllerPythonScript at /Plone/logged_in> Line 29
  Module Products.PlonePAS.tools.membership, line 635, in loginUser
  Module Products.PlonePAS.plugins.cookie_handler, line 91, in login
  Module Products.PluggableAuthService.PluggableAuthService, line 1109, in      updateCredentials
  Module plone.session.plugins.session, line 220, in updateCredentials
  Module plone.session.plugins.session, line 136, in _setupSession
  Module plone.session.plugins.session, line 130, in _getSigningSecret
  Module zope.component._api, line 169, in getUtility
ComponentLookupError: (<InterfaceClass plone.keyring.interfaces.IKeyManager>, '')
```

Any ideas on how to correct the error and what may be causing the site to not display correctly?

Answer (score 1):

From: https://dev.plone.org/ticket/8579

> Reinstall all steps from the "plone.keyring KeyManager Registration" to fix ComponentLookupError: (, '') errors when working in Site Setup

Generally, when upgrading, there are some upgrade steps to run. Being an error on login, it can be a problem to run them in the web interface. So I agree it is better to upgrade to latest 3.X and then to 4.X

Answer (score 0):

I just did something similar, only from 3.1.5.1 to 4.1.4.  It's highly advisable to migrate first to 3.3.5 (the last supported 3x release), then to 4x.